# How to solve a system of linear equations modulo n?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

For example,

$4x - 10y \equiv 8\pmod {20}$

$7x + 2y \equiv 5\pmod {20}$

It resembles linear diophantine equations and the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but I don't know how to actually solve it..

Comment: Similar techniques to those for solving ordinary systems still apply here. Double the top equation and subtract the second; what do you find out?

Comment: When $n$ is squarefree, you can solve the system using Gaussian elimination modulo each prime factor, then compute the overall answer with the Chinese Remainder Theorem. I'm not sure what to do when $n$ isn't squarefree (e.g. 20), though.

Comment: $x -2y = 11$ $mod$ $20$. How do we proceed from here? Do we say $x = 11 + 2y$, substitute that back in and try to work things out from there? 

On a side note, once we get the solutions, will we have to manually check them? I ask because I'm not sure if all our operations are 'invertible'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you can multiply the system by any number that has an inverse, that is $\gcd(x,20)=1$.

*So in particular you cannot multiply or divide by $2,4,5,10$ as you would not multiply or divide by $0$ in a normal non-modular system. Well you can do it, but you'll loose equivalence in the way.*

For instance here we would like to have $4x-3x$. We notice that $7^{-1}=3\pmod {20}$ so let's multiply the second line by $9$.

$\begin{cases} 4x-10y\equiv 8\pmod{20}\\ 7x+2y\equiv 5\pmod{20}\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases} 4x-10y\equiv 8\pmod{20}\\ 3x+18y\equiv 5\pmod{20}\end{cases}$

Now we can subtract two lines like we do in normal systems

$\begin{cases} 4x-10y\equiv 8\pmod{20}\\ x-28y\equiv 3\pmod{20}\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases} 4x-10y\equiv 8\pmod{20}\\ x\equiv 8y+3\pmod{20}\end{cases}$

We now have $x$ and can report in the first equation

$\begin{cases} 32y+12-10y\equiv 8\pmod{20}\\ x\equiv 8y+3\pmod{20}\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases} 2y\equiv 16\pmod{20}\\ x\equiv 8y+3\pmod{20}\end{cases}$

$2$ is not invertible modulo $20$ but since all coefficients are even, we can divide everything by $2$ **including** the modulo.

$\begin{cases} y\equiv 8\pmod{10}\\ x\equiv 8y+3\pmod{20}\end{cases}$

Finally report in second equation to get $x$, by introducing a dummy variable $k$ for expressing $y$

$\begin{cases} y\equiv 8\pmod{10}\\ x\equiv 8(10k+8)+3\pmod{20}\equiv 64+3\equiv 7 \pmod{20}\end{cases}$

I have detailed a lot, since this is apparently your first time solving this.

---

```
Answering question in comment
```

$\begin{cases} 2x-6y\equiv 11\pmod{20}\\ 4x+8y\equiv 9\pmod{20}\end{cases}$

*Rem: for parity reasons this has no solution, but let's do like we ignore that.*

For this one $9$ and $11$ are invertible (and their own inverse), so let's multiply the lines by $9$ and $11$.

You get

$\begin{cases} 2x+14y\equiv 1\pmod{20}\\ 16x+12y\equiv 1\pmod{20}\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases} 2x+14y\equiv 1\pmod{20}\\ 14x-2y\equiv 0\pmod{20}\end{cases}$

Which reduce to $y\equiv 7x\pmod{10}$, and this system has no solution ($2x+14y$ is divisible by $20$).

Comment: Thank you! How would we do it if none of the coefficients had an inverse?

Comment: Then you have to reduce the system by dividing by the $gcd$ of them. For instance we can reduce first equation to $2x-5y\equiv 4\pmod{10}$ and hope for further simplifications. At the end if nothing works, go back to definitions and use $2x-5y=4+10k$ and try to find new equations $\pmod 2$ and $\pmod 5$.

Comment: If we had, say,

$2x - 6y = 11$ $mod$ $20$
$4x + 8y = 7$ $mod$ $20$, how would we proceed?

Comment: A possible way to deal with this case in edit. But it is obvious that for parity reasons, it has no solutions.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{eqnarray}
   4x - 10y \equiv 8\pmod {20} \\
   7x + 2y \equiv 5\pmod {20}
\end{eqnarray}

### Method 1 - Take advantage of a unit coefficient (7)

\begin{align}
   7x + 2y &\equiv 5\pmod {20} \\
   21x + 6y &\equiv 15\pmod {20} \\
   x + 6y &\equiv 15\pmod {20} \\
   x &\equiv 14y + 15 \pmod{20} \\
   \hline
   4(14y + 15) - 10y &\equiv 8\pmod {20} \\
   46y + 60 &\equiv 8 \pmod{20} \\
   6y &\equiv 8 \pmod{20} \\
   3y &\equiv 4 \pmod{10} \\
   21y &\equiv 28 \pmod{10} \\
   y &\equiv 8 \pmod{10} \\
   y &= 8 + 10 t \\
   \hline
   x &\equiv 14(8 + 10 t) + 15 \pmod{20} \\
   x &\equiv 112 + 140t + 15 \pmod{20} \\
   x &\equiv 7 \pmod{20} \\
   y &\equiv 8 \pmod{10} \\
\end{align}

### Method 2 - Convert to prime-power moduli

\begin{eqnarray}
   2y &\equiv 0\pmod 4 \\
   3x + 2y &\equiv 1\pmod 4 \\
   \hline
   y &\equiv 0 \pmod 2 \\
   \hline
   3x &\equiv 1\pmod 4 \\
   9x &\equiv 3\pmod 4 \\
   x &\equiv 3 \pmod 4
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
   4x &\equiv 3\pmod 5 \\
   2x + 2y &\equiv 0\pmod 5 \\
   \hline
   -4x &\equiv -3 \pmod 5 \\
   x &\equiv 2 \pmod 5 \\
   \hline
   4 + 2y &\equiv 0\pmod 5 \\
   2 + y &\equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
   y &\equiv 3 \pmod 5
\end{eqnarray}

$\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
   x \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \\
   x \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \\
\end{array}
\right\}
\implies
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
   5x \equiv 15 \pmod{20} \\
   -4x \equiv -8 \pmod{20} \\
\end{array}
\right\}
\implies
x \equiv 7 \pmod{20}$

$\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
   y \equiv 0 \pmod 2\\
   y \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \\
\end{array}
\right\}
\implies
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
   -5y \equiv 0 \pmod{10} \\
   6y \equiv 18 \pmod{10} \\
\end{array}
\right\}
\implies
y \equiv 8 \pmod{10}$